# remove all double quotes in a file.txt

Tags: cmd

What I have to do is a batch script that:

_read a file line by line

_remove all the double quote characters writing the result in a file

My attempt was a script like:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ("%GRUPPI3%.txt") do (
SET VARIAB=%%a
SET RESULT=%VARIAB:"=%
echo %RESULT% >> output.txt
)
```

After some try I realized that the PROBLEM IS THE VARIABLE "VARIAB"!
Doing an echo of VARIAB the result is null or an old value (like an old line read by the variable %%a). (Why "VARIAB" doesn't become a copy of "%%a" as I would expect?) 
I can't understand such a behaviour...

Someone know the solution?

Thanks
Cristian

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
 for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ("%GRUPPI3%.txt") do (
  SET "VARIAB=%%a"
  IF DEFINED variab (
   SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
   SET "RESULT=!VARIAB:"=!"
   ECHO(!RESULT!
   ENDLOCAL
  )
 )
)>newfile.txt
GOTO :EOF
```

This should fix your problem. I changed the detination file to suit my system. If you want to append to the destination file, use `>>` in place of `>`

Comment: Oh, fine. So if you could click on the big empty click to the left of the reply, that will mark the response as accepted and logically close the question, award points and so on. BTW - it's characteristic of `for/f` that empty lines and lines beginning <kbd>;</kbd> will be skipped...